# ASP .NET WebAPI and correct routing

Tags: swagger, asp.net-web-api-routing, swashbuckle

There is a WebAPI v1 controller with the following set of methods:

```
 public class MailMessagesController : ApiController
 {
     [HttpPost]
     [ActionName("Attachments")]
     public HttpResponseMessage Attachments([FromUri] int id) {...}

     [HttpPost]
     public HttpResponseMessage Post() {...}
 }
```

And respective routing (second route is used for a couple other controllers as well):

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "mailMessages",
    routeTemplate: "v1/mailMessages/{id}/{*action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "mailMessages", action = "" }
);

routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Widget",
    routeTemplate: "v1/widgets/{controller}"
);
```

So you see that the basic idea above is to post new messages with `POST` and post new attachments (also with `POST`) to an existing mail-message.

The problem appears when you try to link Swagger/Swashbuckle  to the above setup, it basically complains (errors out) that

> Multiple operations with path 'v1/widgets/mailMessages' and method
>   'POST'

And this is quite understandable, since it considers `Attachments`-method as just another `POST` as well.

What would be the appropriate routing to ignore/remove `POST` of mailMesage with ID, **when action is not specified**?

(I know about the trick with Swashbuckle's `ResolveConflictingActions`, but I'd rather create correct routing than hide inconsistencies through "swagging".)

Comment: A post with no body, maybe that should not be a post...

Comment: @HelderSepulveda  well, probably true.  This is not my code actually. So I don't want to chime in greatly in the design :)